# Logging all filters on Wildfly/Jboss

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Is there a way I can get the list of all filters a request have passed into (including filters in jars that are not my app, some framework, for example)?

I want to get the list of filters for a request for both jboss and wildfly. We are upgrading to wildfly and I have a theory that some filters are executing in a different order or not being executed at all, and I would like to confirm that in some way... is it possible without changing all the filter's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up putting a `log.info` in each filter.

Enabling undertow's request debugging also helps.